# Setting pointer size by application

Tags: mouse, accessibility, adobe-photoshop, cursor

Generally, I prefer to have the size of the pointer one notch above "normal," this makes it easier to spot in my high resolution display. However, when using brushes in Photoshop, this larger pointer setting causes the brush to appear larger than it really is; this results in a brushstroke smaller than what you expect based on pointer size.

My question: is there a way for the pointer to automatically switch to normal size when using Photoshop? Or if not automatically, perhaps a script where I can use a keyboard shortcut to switch between 2 pointer sizes.

Comment: It should be doable via AppleScript. I'm using **BetterTouchTool App** for this. In my case i'm toggling between big and small pointer size if MS Teams is started or closed.